# Что делать если библиотека pillow (python) при картинке которая имеет прозрачный фон, при вырисовке ставит черный фон?

Tags: python, изображения, pillow

У меня есть код на pillow и код на quickchart на котором написана бубликовая диаграмма, при создании диаграммы фон прозрачный (я проверял через im1.show() ), считаю что проблема в самой библиотеке pillow которая создает фон картинке с прозрачным фоном

```
im = Image.open('prime.png')

qc = QuickChart()
qc.width = 500
qc.height = 300
qc.version = '2'
qc.background_color = ""
qc.config = {
  "type": 'doughnut',
  "data": {
    "datasets": [
      {
        "data": [43, 21],
        "backgroundColor": ['rgb(173 225 232)', 'rgb(33 170 184)'],
        "borderWidth": 0,
      },
    ],
  },
  "options": {
    "cutoutPercentage": 80,
    "legend": {
      "display": "false",
    },
    "plugins": {
      "datalabels": {
        "display": "false",
      },
    },
  },
}
url = qc.get_url()
raw = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
im1 = Image.open(raw)
im1.save("diagramma.png")

diagramma = Image.open("diagramma.png")
Image.Image.paste(im, diagramma, (100, 400))
```

Comment: А `print(im)` что выводит? `im1` и `diagramma` явно с прозрачностью - проверял там будет `<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=500x300 ...`, а `mode=RGBA` означает, что есть поддержка прозрачности, т.к. есть альфа-канал

Comment: print(im) выводит -
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=3264x3264 at 0x3DC5508>

Comment: Как вижу там mode=RGB

Comment: Что можно сделать в таком случае?

Comment: Можно сконвертировать в RGBA, но это не поможет. Думаю, я смог разобраться - опишу в ответе :)

Comment: А как можно сделать конвертацию? и почему это не поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением будет вставка прозрачного изображения и его же как маску:

```
Image.Image.paste(im, diagramma, (100, 400), mask=diagramma)
```

---

Ниже я покажу другие варианты и почему они не помогут

**input.jpg:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Общий код:**

```
# pip install requests
import requests

# pip install pillow
from PIL import Image

# pip install quickchart.io
from quickchart import QuickChart


qc = QuickChart()
qc.width = 500
qc.height = 300
qc.version = '2'
qc.background_color = ""
qc.config = {
    "type": 'doughnut',
    "data": {
        "datasets": [
            {
                "data": [43, 21],
                "backgroundColor": ['rgb(173 225 232)', 'rgb(33 170 184)'],
                "borderWidth": 0,
            },
        ],
    },
    "options": {
        "cutoutPercentage": 80,
        "legend": {
            "display": "false",
        },
        "plugins": {
            "datalabels": {
                "display": "false",
            },
        },
    },
}
url = qc.get_url()

raw = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
diagramma = Image.open(raw)
```

#### Вариант `input.jpg` будет `RGB`, вставка в него `RGBA`:

```
...

img = Image.open('input.jpg')
Image.Image.paste(img, diagramma, (10, 10))

img.save('diagramma-full.png')
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### Вариант `input.jpg` будет `RGB` с конвертацией в `RGBA`, вставка в него `RGBA`:

```
...
img = Image.open('input.jpg')
img = img.convert('RGBA')

Image.Image.paste(img, diagramma, (10, 10))

img.save('diagramma-full.png')
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### Использование маски:

```
...

img = Image.open('input.jpg')
Image.Image.paste(img, diagramma, (10, 10), mask=diagramma)

img.save('diagramma-full.png')
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]